# mysql join multiples

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the `products` table as the master, I want to list all products. If the product has a description in table `prod_desc`, I want to pull it in.  Also, if the product has a manufacturer description, I want to pull it in. I want the product row to display once, whether it has a prod description, manufacturer description, one, both or neither.

A left join works well for one external lookup, but the second one messes it up.

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.a=t3.a
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.b=t2.b
```

Comment: What do you mean by messes it up?

Comment: It looks like there is a row printed if either join matches. I want t1 to print once whether it matches one, both or neither.

Comment: @úser665065 could it be you have multiple values in t2,t3 for a single t1.a? If that's the case you will get more than one row for each product.

Comment: Some sample inputs and expected outputs would help. Are product descriptions and manufacturer descriptions stored in the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like your "`select *`" might be the issue. but I cannot tell for sure what you mean by "mess it up." Try to select only what you want, and see if that solves it.

For example,

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t3 
    ON t1.a = t3.a
  LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.b = t2.b
```

Comment: OK. Sorry **** I've got a problem in my test data. The b columns in table t2,t3,t4 should be unique. They are acting as the foreign keys for table t1.

Comment: @user665065: so is your problem resolved now that you found you had bad data? Or is it still open?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to "roll up" the descriptions in case there are multiple product descriptions for the same product or multiple manufacturer descriptions for the same product.

```
Select P.Id, P...
    , Group_Concat( PD.desc ) As DescriptionList
    , Group_Concat( PMD.desc ) As MfrDescriptionList
From products As P
    Left Join prod_desc As PD
        On PD.product_id = P.id
    Left Join prod_mfr_desc As PMD
        On PMD.product_id = P.id
Group By P.id
```